# Accessing a file in src/main/resources while using docker

Tags: java, spring, docker

I am just learning how to use docker with java so I am very open to advice.

My project worked top to bottom no problem; but now that I am trying to do a local docker deploy I am having issues with accessing a folder location.

I am running everything locally; desktop is windows.

What I am trying to do is take ffmpeg.exe and at runtime move the exe file out to beside the jar.

I am guessing with docker there is a different way to do this; but I am unsure how and looking for help.

Here is the whole method:

```
static public String ExportResource(String resourceName) throws Exception {
        InputStream stream = null;
        OutputStream resStreamOut = null;
        String jarFolder;
        stream = VideoTranscode.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);//note that each / is a directory down in the "jar tree" been the jar the root of the tree
        if (stream == null) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot get resource \"" + resourceName + "\" from Jar file.");
        }

        int readBytes;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        jarFolder = new File(VideoTranscode.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).getParentFile().getPath().replace('\\', '/');
        if (!resourceFileAlreadyCopied(resourceName)) {
            try {

                resStreamOut = new FileOutputStream(jarFolder + resourceName);
                while ((readBytes = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    resStreamOut.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            } finally {
                stream.close();
                resStreamOut.close();
            }
        }

        return jarFolder + resourceName;

    }
```

I am getting the NPE here:

`jarFolder = new File(VideoTranscode.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).getParentFile().getPath().replace('\\', '/');`

[image: My directory structure]

Here is my docker file

```
FROM maven:3-openjdk-8
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: There is no `File` when sourcing resources from a jar/war file. A `java.util.File` must be an actual resource on the file-system. As this is inside a jar or war it doesn't adhere to that and thus it isn't a file. Just stream the content directly instead of going through a file.

Comment: Hey @M.Deinum thanks, I am new to streaming as well, but ultimately I am trying to grab ffmpeg.exe and pass it to a process builder to run the exe. Is this possible with a stream? 

Also this works fine with the jar, in my non-docker deployment my code goes in and grabs the stream and copies the file to beside the jar, but now it gets an NPE on the line I pointed out.